# How to share image Generated Bitmap

Tags: java, android, imageview, share

People would like to know how I share an image generated within the app,

in the app's scope the person writing in the text view it captures and generates an image would like to share that image via whats or email.

```
private void gerarQRCode() {

    String texto = edtTexto.getText().toString();
    MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();

    try {

        BitMatrix bitmatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(texto, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 2000, 2000);
        BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
        Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitmatrix);
        ivQRCode.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Write the `Bitmap` to a file on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), using the `compress()` method

Step #2: [Set up `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html) to be able to serve files from where you are storing the bitmap

Step #3: Use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` representing that bitmap

Step #4: [Use `ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-binary-content) to offer that bitmap to other apps for sharing purposes